# Error : Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '>' in C:\Instalar Xampp\htdocs\PRACTICA\guardar.php on line 26

Tags: php, html

**Hola buen día**
Estoy haciendo un proyecto sobre un formulario con html, css, php y mysql(phpmyadmin), este es el código del error(php)

```
<?php

$usuario = "root";
$password = "";
$servidor = "localhost";
$basededatos = "formulario";


$conexion = mysqli_connect($servidor,$usuario,"") or die ("Error con el servidor de la base de datos");

$bd = mysqli_select_db($conexion, $basededatos) or die ("Error conexion al conectarse a la base de datos");

$nombre=$_POST['nombre'];
$raspado=$_POST['raspado'];
$sabor=$_POST['sabor'];
$cantidad=$_POST['cantidad'];

$sql="INSERT INTO datos VALUES ('$nombre','$raspado','$sabor','$cantidad' )";

$ejecutar=mysql_query($conexion, $sql);

if(!$ejecutar){
echo"Hubo un error";

}else{
   echo"Datos guardados correctamente" <br> <a href='index.html'>volver</a>;
}

?>
```

Según tengo un error en la línea 26 que viene siendo el ultimo ELSE en donde se dice que los datos son guardados correctamente ya estuve buscando errores, y si tenia por ejemplo después de ECHO le había puesto un = , se lo borré y me decía el mismo error, seguí buscando y en vez de ROOT tenía roor también lo corregí y aún sigo teniendo el mismo error.

Si me pueden ayudar se los agradezco mucho :D

Comment: Las etiquetas HTML como br y a van entre comillas y deben ir en todo caso concatenados con un .

Comment: Hola, ya lo hice y me sigue marcando el mismo error

Comment: Agrega en tu pregunta cómo lo hiciste

Comment: Hola beta, ya pude hacerlo, borré el salto de linea y a la a le agregué comillas como tu me lo dijiste, MUCHAS GRACIAS

Comment: echo"Datos guardados correctamente"," <a href='index.html'>Volver</a>"; MIRA DE ESTA MANERA ME SALIÓ Y YA ME INGRESA LOS DATOS EN LA BASE DE DATOS

Answer (score 0):

El problema que tienes es que las etiquetas HTML que son aquellas que van entre **`<>`** no las reconoce PHP de forma directa, lo que debes hacer es encerrarlas entre comillas y concatenarlas a la cadena de texto que planeas mostrar así:

```
echo"Datos guardados correctamente"."<a href='index.html'>volver</a>";
```

Answer (score 0):

aqui tu error

```
else{
echo"Datos guardados correctamente" <br> <a href='index.html'>volver</a>;
}
```

deberia ser

```
else{ echo "Datos guardados".'<a href='index.html'>volver</a>'
```

el problema es que estas cerrando el echo y no estas concatenando solo agregas el html al final.